# CAML Query and using non user credentials

Tags: 2013, caml-query

I have 2 sites for 2 different groups. One group has access to site1 and one group has site2. Each group does not have access to the others site.

I have a query however that needs to access each site upon entry of a field to see if it exists. Unfortunately the query will fail due to the user not having access to one of the sites.

Is there a way that I can pass credentials that have access to query?

This is my code:

```
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext('https://mysite.sharepoint.com/site/site1/');
var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('list');
var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\'Title\'/>' +
    '<Value Type=\'Text\'>'+check+'</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>');
this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery); 
clientContext.load(collListItem, 'Include(Id, DisplayName)');
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can impersonate only using server side code.

So either provide read access or create a custom web part for displaying data.

Comment: Can't give these users read access, how would I go about creating a web part to do that?

Comment: You need to use Visual Studio. And create a SharePoint project. Then use a visual web part. Drop a GridView control. And use elevated to query data.

Comment: Can I use my script to call a C# code to impersonate a user that would have access to both sites?

Comment: In that case you should deploy that c# code as a web service

Comment: How would I call that functionality in the javascript before I run my query?